# Modify elements position and rotation before appending

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a hopeless javascript newbie and I'm trying to insert dynamically created image elements into DOM while positioning and rotating them randomly.

At the moment I'm basically doing this:

1. Create an array with all the image file paths
2. Create a div with dynamically created name and insert into DOM
3. Generate 20 different instances of the images and insert into DOM to the corresponding div
4. Rotate each image by a random amount and position each image randomly. For rotation I use the jQuery rotate plugin.

I have a feeling I'm doing all this in a very stupid way since I'm first inserting the elements into DOM and THEN manipulating their position and rotation.

Is there a way to first do everything in virtual memory and finally insert the elements to DOM when all the manipulations have already been done?

Here is my current code (sorry for the noobish quality):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),


function movieCreator(movieName, generateAmount){

var contents=new Array (

'<img class="film '+movieName+'" src="images/'+movieName+'01.png" alt="'+movieName+'" />',

'<img class="film '+movieName+'" src="images/'+movieName+'02.png" alt="'+movieName+'" />',

'<img class="film '+movieName+'" src="images/'+movieName+'03.png" alt="'+movieName+'" />',

'<img class="film '+movieName+'" src="images/'+movieName+'04.png" alt="'+movieName+'" />',

'<img class="film '+movieName+'" src="images/'+movieName+'05.png" alt="'+movieName+'" />',

'<img class="film '+movieName+'" src="images/'+movieName+'06.png" alt="'+movieName+'" />',

'<img class="film '+movieName+'" src="images/'+movieName+'07.png" alt="'+movieName+'" />'   

);

var tmp='';
var dynamicIdName = 'box'+movieName;
var dynamicIdCall = '#box'+movieName;
wrapper.append("<div id='"+dynamicIdName+"' class='moviebox'></div>");


var random
for (i=0; i < generateAmount;){
random = Math.floor(Math.random()*contents.length);
tmp += contents[random];
i++
};

$(dynamicIdCall).append(tmp);

$(".film").each(function(){ 
    randomrot = Math.floor(Math.random()*360); 
    randomposX = Math.floor(Math.random()*200); 
    randomposY = Math.floor(Math.random()*200); 
    $(this).rotate(randomrot);
    $(this).css({'top': randomposY -40});
    $(this).css({'left': randomposX -40});

});


    wrapper.on('click','.film',function(){
    imageControl(this);
    });



} //end movieCreator

    movieCreator('terminator', 20);
    movieCreator('rambo', 20);
    movieCreator('godfather', 20);
    movieCreator('matrix', 20);
    movieCreator('kingkong', 20);


}); //dom ready
```

Comment: JavaScript is already utilizing memory client-side, but until elements are on the page one way or another either rendered at the time of load or after via JavaScript, you can't manipulate them until they exist to the DOM in some shape or form. That said, what is your actual problem, is this not loading? breaking? taking way to long? freezing up the browser? other?

Comment: It is not virtual memory, but you can create a DOM element detached from DOM and do whatever you like on it. if you create element with jQuery you can obtain element wrapped in jQuery to which you can apply jQuery functions. Funtionalities that require the element to be in the layout cannot be done though, like getting height of element. applying CSS will work, not sure about rotate, if it's just setting CSS it should work as well.

Comment: @chris I guess the problem is that my current code is taking too long. Clients can clearly see the elements being created and manipulated. I tried to apply these 
    $(this).rotate(randomrot);
    $(this).css({'top': randomposY -40});
    $(this).css({'left': randomposX -40});
to the "tmp" variable instead of getting the $('.film') class but that resulted in console error telling that the image element has no rotate method.

Comment: Well, I wont say you don't have a lot going on, have you considered rendering the images server-side with the attributes you need, similar to how your doing it now with just javascript. Maybe by loading the images into the DOM first then calling rotate on them may speed things up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm trying to cover lots of things here...

You have an unexpected `,`:

```
var wrapper = $('#wrapper'),
                        ---^
```

You can use `[]` instead of `new Array()`:

```
var contents = [ ... ]
```

Careful, `i` is global, use `var`. Also, you can move `i++` to the `for` loop:

```
for (var i = 0; i < generateAmount; i++){
   ---^---                       ---^---
```

Those are common beginner mistakes. Try to grasp those concepts first and then if you want best performance, append everything at last. You can then refactor everything to this, I commented a few things:

```
var $wrap = $('#wrapper')

var movieCreator = function (name, ammount) {

  // Utility function to keep it DRY
  var rand = function (len) {
    return ~~(Math.random() * len) // ~~ trick Math.floor
  }

  // Cache your container in a variable
  var $container = $('<div/>', {
    id: 'box' + name,
    'class': 'moviebox'
  })

  // Generate iamges with an array
  // to keep it DRY
  var imgs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
    imgs.push(
      '<img ' +
      'class="film '+ name +'"'+
      'src="images/'+ name +'0'+ i + '.png"'+ // If no with more than 10...
      'alt="'+ name +'"'+
      '/>'
    )
  }

  var randImgs = []
  for (var i = 0; i < ammount; i++)
    randImgs.push(imgs[rand(imgs.length)])

  // Attach events before inserting in DOM
  // that way you don't need delegation with on()
  var $imgs = $(randImgs.join(''))
  $imgs
  .click(function(){
    imageControl(this)
  })
  .each(function(){
    var rot = rand(360),
        posX = rand(200),
        posY = rand(200)
    $(this)
      .css({
        top: posY - 40 + 'px', // use units (px, em)
        left: posX - 40 + 'px'
      })
      .rotate(rot)
  })

  // Finally insert in DOM. It already has
  // all events attached and position changed
  $wrap.append($container.append($imgs))
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your kind help! And for taking the time to explain these things. I will go and try to insert the improved code now and see if it works!

Comment: I changed a few things, but I'd suggest not copy/pasting but actually writing it yourself and try every piece of code to see what it does. There are a lot of probably new concepts there.

Comment: Finished testing and it works! That's a big improvement and thanks for schooling me! There is one thing I don't understand from the code:
why are you creating the container variable with the dollar sign var $container? What's the difference between just var container?

Comment: By the way I just feel like I have to express being in awe with your answer. How on earth can you take such a complex piece of code some newbie wrote and understand the logic of it that quickly? This is for me truly amazing! How many years have you been writing code to get that good? :D

Comment: I've been a newbie too, I've done these mistakes. When you understand how the language really works then it's easy to refactor code like this. To your question, the dollar sign is just to remind you that the variable is a jQuery object. It makes no difference in practice.